# How to read file content into a struct line by line in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Here, I am trying to read the contents of a file line by line and create a struct for each line. The problem is when I print the list of words, every single one of them is the last word of the file (which is } in this sample). I believe since **line** changes frequently and I pass a pointer to a char, **value** of every struct changes as well. I've been trying to fix this problem for nearly a day without any luck. What's a good way to read every word into a struct and link each struct to the linked list?

Note that there are some helper methods used below. I've tested them multiple times and they are working.

**Token struct**

```
    typedef struct token
    {
     char* value;
     struct token* next;
    }TOKEN;
```

**File content**

```
 target1:
 dependency1
 {
 command1,
 command2
 }
```

**Main**

```
    TOKEN *head = NULL;
// represents each formatted line from the script file
char* line = malloc(161*sizeof(char));

FILE* fileRead = openFile("RawRules.txt", "r");

while((line = readLine(line, fileRead)) != NULL) 
{
    head = add(head, line);
}

displaylist(head);
freeNodes(head);
fclose(fileRead);
```

**Add function** Modified from http://cprogramminglanguage.net/singly-linked-list-c-source-code.aspx

```
 TOKEN* add(TOKEN *head, char* value){
 TOKEN *tmp;

if(head == NULL){
    head=(TOKEN *)malloc(sizeof(TOKEN));
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Error! memory is not available\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    head-> value = value;
    head-> next = head; 
}else{
    tmp = head;

    while (tmp-> next != head)
        tmp = tmp-> next;
    tmp-> next = (TOKEN *)malloc(sizeof(TOKEN)); 
    if(tmp -> next == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory is not available\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp = tmp-> next;
    tmp-> value = value;
    tmp-> next = head;
}
return head;
```

}

**readline function**

```
 // reads a line of a file into buffer
 char* readLine(char* buffer, FILE* file) {
buffer = fgets(buffer, 161, file);
return buffer;
 }
```

**This did not fix the problem either**

```
    while(true) 
{
    char* ll = malloc(161*sizeof(char));
    ll = readLine(ll, fileRead);

    f(ll != NULL)
        head = add(head, ll);
    else 
        break;
}
```

Sorry, I progammed in C like billion years ago, so call me a noob!

Comment: its going to read one line of the file into 'line'.

Comment: each line is supposed to be at most 160 characters long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `add()` function, you're simply assigning a `char *`, rather than allocating any new memory (and then copying) for each string.  So each `TOKEN` ends up pointing at the original buffer.  As you're using a single buffer at the top-level, you're overwriting it over and over again.

In short: You need a separate buffer for each line.  One way (not necessarily the best way) is to do the following inside `add()`:

```
int len = strlen(value);

...

tmp->value = malloc(len+1); /* +1 for null terminator */
strncpy(tmp->value, value, len+1);
```

Remember that at some point, you'll need to `free()` all of these extra buffers.

Comment: Your code works 99% well or maybe my code is still broken somewhere. The output will be correct except that the first line of the output (i.e. the first struct data) will be the last line of the file. Also, there is an extra struct at the very end of the linked list. It contains the same line (last line of the file)